# App doesn't load css and json files in an folder in root after updated angular app to version 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i'm facing a problem after upgrading angular cli app to v7.
In my app there is a folder called "public" where i store my `css` and settings in `json` format. I load the `css` inside index.html and the settings `json` when the app loads (in `ngOnInit`).

It works fine in with angular 6. After update to 7 the app shows error "Refused to apply style from xxx because its MIME type(text/html) is not supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled" and error "the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found). It seems the folder is not accessible or not served by ng serve.

I double checked that it worked with angular 6. 
Do i need to include the folder in `angular.json`?

I need the folder to be located in the root folder ( in the dist folder in productive mode) where the index.html lies.

Does anybody have this problem too? I hope you can help.

Comment: I think you should add the entry to `angular.json`: 
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss",
  "../public/your_style_sheet.css"
],

Comment: The whole setting folder should be accessible to the index.html. It should lie inside the same folder as "src" folder.  By following your hint with the "..." super folder i edit the angular.json to assets: [ "../public"]. But the following error shows "The ".../public" asset path must start the the project source root".

Comment: just adding `..` won't make sense, what i meant was use relative path to point to your public folder. Can you at least share how is your project structured? directory placements?

Comment: My project structure looks like this: 
- public: where setting css and json lie
- src: source code of the project
- angular.json
- package.json

As i said the public folder and the src folder lie in the same level (in root folder).